# Will cout function of c++ stop printing if it comes across a null character(positioned in middle of array) in character array

Tags: c++

Will cout function of c++ stop printing  if it comes across a null character(positioned in middle of array) in character array?

Comment: Here we like you try before asking. Please take a moment to read the guide how to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `std::cout` isn't a function.  It's an object (specifically an output stream object).

Its `<<` operator is overloaded.  The overloads which are particularly relevant are those which accept strings.

- If we pass a `std::string`, then `<<` will output every character in the string.
- If we pass a C-style string (`char*`), then `<<` will output every character up to, but not including, the first NUL character encountered.  Note that for malformed input (containing no NUL), this can lead to undefined behaviour, due to reading beyond the bounds of the array.

The other (unformatted) output operation is `write()`, which accepts a character array and a length.  That outputs exactly the number of characters specified, including any NULs encountered.